# Cómo validar los campos de un V-CONTAINER

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Tengo un proyecto con VUE Js en el que, para editar algunas tablas creadas mediante v-data-table. Pero no encuentro información sobre cómo validar que no se dejen los campos vacíos de ese mismo v-container. Podría ayudarme con el método o función para realizarlo?? Este es el código de mi v-container:

```
<v-container>
           <v-row>
               <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                   <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.name" label="Concepto"></v-text-field>
               </v-col>
               <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                   <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.amount" label="Monto"></v-text-field>
               </v-col>
           </v-row>
</v-container>
```

Todo esta dentro de un v-card

Answer (score 0):

Podrías revisar esta pagina oficial de vuetify en la cual explican el uso de validación para formularios, V-CONTAINER y v-text-field

[Vuetify includes simple validation through the rules prop.](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#validation)